# CefGlue remote debugging port not working

Tags: remote-debugging, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I have built two applications with CefGlue. Both share the same code base where I set the remote debugging port. But for one it works and for the other it does not. By this I mean that the remote debugging page is available but it's just blank white.

Do you have any suggestions where to look for possible problems? Is there something else I could have made to break remote debugging?

**Edit**: I had a look at the HTML and it is completely empty. And at least "Inspectable WebContents" should be there I guess.

**Edit**: I found the following messages in debug.log:

```
[0407/103613:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(304)] locale_file_path.empty()
[0407/103613:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(567)] Could not load locale pak for en-US
[0407/103613:ERROR:data_pack.cc(121)] Bad data pack version: got 79674351, expected 4
[0407/103613:ERROR:resource_bundle.cc(677)] Failed to load C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\matchmycolor\svn\C_Colibri_Src\trunk_3\bin\Debug\cef.pak
Some features may not be available.
[0407/103613:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(501)] locale resources are not loaded
[0407/103613:ERROR:proxy_service_factory.cc(104)] Cannot use V8 Proxy resolver in single process mode.
```

Apart that I miss the locale files the interesting line is this:

```
[0407/103613:ERROR:data_pack.cc(121)] Bad data pack version: got 79674351, expected 4
```

Comment: As ideas: check windows firewall, and don't forget to ask on ceforum.

Comment: @fddima: If it would be firewall it would affect both applications, wouldn't it? I have posted it [here](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=14065)

Comment: Windows firewall work per-application level. By default it s not prevent listen on localhost, but depends from choices.

Comment: @fddima: Both applications I started as exe or and Visual Studio. I guess firewall would not affect starting from VS.

Comment: it always affect. If vs hosting process enabled, then .vshost.exe is executed, if no - original exe. For firewall there is no any difference how you run or debug application. Second application has all .pak files?

Comment: I checked the firewall and made sure all .pak files are there. Still only white screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The version of cef.pak was wrong for one application. After changing it everything worked. The log file gave the correct hint.

Comment: You are not newbie with CEF, i'm even did not propose look in log. It is of course should be first thing. :)

Comment: @fddima: You are right. And when I looked at the file I was not careful enough to realize the hint was there. Sorry for your effort. I have learned the lesson.